# Order Isomorphism Definition Question

Tags: logic, order-theory

When reading the definition of an order Isomorphism again, it occurred to me - are there examples where a function between two ordered (for some orders) sets is bijective and is a homomorphism, but whose inverse is not a homomorphism?

I assume there are, otherwise the extra condition of the inverse having to be a homomorphism would be redundant, but I can't think of any.

Comment: Maybe you are only thinking about linear orders, and if $L$ is a linear order and $f:L\rightarrow O$ where $O$ is an ordered set is non decreasing and bijective, then it is an isomorphism. Now for a counter example, take $N_1=\mathbb{N}^{>0}$ ordered by divisilility and $N_2=\mathbb{N}^{>0}$ standardly ordered. The identity $N_1\rightarrow N_2$ is non decreasing and bijective but not an isomorphism.

Comment: The general notion of isomorphism is a homomorphism that has an inverse homomorphism. And even in those cases of structures for which bijective homomorphisms turn out to be isomorphisms, it is not uncommon for people to find "has an inverse homomorphism" to be a more natural statement than "is bijective". It is also common, IMO, for people to use the term inverse to refer to what you call an inverse that is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, if $X,Y$ are posets, a function $f$ is an order isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ if

- $f$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$.$\\[4pt]$

  $x\le y$ if and only if $f(x) \le f(y)$.

It's then automatic that $f^{-1}$ is an order isomorphism from $Y$ to $X$.

But if $f$ is only required to be a bijective homomorphism, then $f$ need not be an order isomorphism.

For a simple example, let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ with the partial order whose only strict comparison is $a < b$, and let $Y=\{a,b,c\}$ with the partial order whose strict comparisons are $a < b < c$.

Then if $f:X\to Y$ is given by
$$f(a)=a,\;\;f(b)=c,\;\;f(c)=b$$
we get that $f$ is a bijective homomorphism, but not an isomorphism.

For an even simpler example, let $X,Y$ be sets such that $|X|=|Y| > 1$.

For $X$, let the partial order be such that no two distinct elements are comparable, and for $Y$, let the partial order be such that there exist two distinct elements which are comparable.

Then any function from $X$ to $Y$ is a homomorphism, but $X,Y$ are not isomorphic. Hence any bijective function from $X$ to $Y$ is a bijective homomorphism, but not an isomorphism.

On the other hand, if $X,Y$ are *totally* ordered, then a bijective homomorphism from $X$ to $Y$ is, in fact, an isomorphism, since for two distinct elements of $Y$, their comparison must be the same as the comparison of their element-wise inverse images. Thus, the "if and only if" requirement holds true.

Comment: What is an order homomorphism?

Comment: An order-preserving map.

Comment: I read the definition of an order-isomorphism to be a function from $X$ to $Y$ so that it is bijective, is an order homomorphism and has, as its inverse, an order homomorphism from $Y$ to $X$... Is this not correct?

Comment: @Isky Mathews: Yes, that's correct. Equivalently, it's a bijection $f:X\to Y$ which satisfies $x\le y$ if and only if $f(x)\le f(y)$.